# I can't get Jquery Hover (or click, etc.) to work with generated <div>s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with a seemingly simple Jquery function.

Basically, the small/med/big etc. buttons create a grid of >div>s within a >div>.
They all have a class of .colorblock
I want to add a class or change the background color upon hovering over these divs.

I've included the jsfiddle (but I'm creating this on my own computer - ignore the fact that the button box butts into the grid on jsfiddle, I can fix that...eventually), and copied the 'problem areas' below. The grid is created successfully, but I can't get anything to interact with the <\div class="colorblock"> after that.

https://jsfiddle.net/pqtn50fc/4/
Also - is there a way to use a variable defined earlier in jQuery directly in the

```
 .append('<div style="height: jVARIABLE"> </div>')
```

? It's simpler to calculate the size and put it in the loop instead of making different loops for each div. I tried changing all the divs after they were created but it kept lagging/freezing.

```
HTML____________

    <div id="colorspace">

    </div>

CSS____________

.colorblock {
  float: left;
  outline: 2px solid blue;
}

.black {
 background-color: black;
}

.smallcolorblock {
  width: 21.875px;
  height: 21.875px;
}

JQUERY____________

var smallH = '<div class="smallcolorblock colorblock"></div>'

$('#small').click(function(){
    $('.colorblock').remove();
    for (var i = 1; i <= 32*32 ; i++) {     
        $('#colorspace').append(smallH);
        };

$('.colorblock').hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background", getRandomColor()),
    function(){
        $(this).css("background", "white");
    };

 $('.colorblock').hover(function() {
     $(this).addClass("black");
   });
```

Comment: Since you are creating the element after, you may need to delegate the event try with `$('#colorspace').on('hover','.colorblock',function(){ ---- `

Comment: Bind to a container and use the .on method.  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @nurdyguy  - I'll try that now, thanks!

Comment: @paul roub - thanks, I didn't know how to find that question -looks like it answers as well

Comment: @HenryHardingMcCall  This is a very commonly asked question.  Paul was pointing you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements which has a much more elaborate answer but is essentially what Dani and I said.

Comment: @nurdyguy thanks a lot! i had another question deeper in that seems to be asked a lot, but the answers don't put the style directly in the div creation ---from above: Also - is there a way to use a variable defined earlier in jQuery directly in the
 .append('<div style="height: jVARIABLE"> </div>')
? It's simpler to calculate the size and put it in the loop instead of making different loops for each div. I tried changing all the divs after they were created but it kept lagging/freezing.

Comment: Depending on scope, you can pull in a javascript variable and use string concatination to do what you are describing.  '<div style="height:' + varheight + 'px;" />.......'

Comment: @nurdyguy thanks a lot, works perfectly. any idea why this .on() statement isn't working?
$('#colorspace').on("hover", '.colorblock', function(){
  $(this).css("background", "red");
 });

Comment: @HenryHardingMcCall The div that is being appended, does it have a class on it?

Comment: @nurdyguy yes it does, '.colorblock' - it has two classes, div class = "bigcolorblock colorblock">
and it is getting the CSS attributes from both classes after being appended, but won't change after that

Comment: Is the bind inside of a $( document ).ready(... or similar?  https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @nurdyguy yes the document.ready surrounds it all

Comment: @nurdyguy I got it to work by changing hover to click, but then it still won't work with hover. I tried adding the second function to hover (to remove the class after the hover ends) and it still won't work. thanks regardless!

Comment: I don't think I've used hover this way but I know I've use mouseenter and mouseleave for this kind of thing.  The unfortunate thing is you then need to write the function twice.  If you are just changing background color you might also accomplish this via pure css.

Comment: @nurdyguy I've managed to do a workaround with mouseover for this project. really appreciate you sticking with me haha

Comment: Np, glad you got it working.